# Adding Banshee to the sound indicator

Tags: 10.10, indicator, banshee, indicator-sound

How to put Banshee into sound the indicator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the menu, Edit->Preferences, and then the extension tab, you need to turn off the old notification area and application indicator extensions (if they're on) and turn on 2 extensions, MPRIS Support and Sound Menu Integration:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for how many of your answers have screenshots to show how to do stuff. That's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

you have to enable Indicator plugin in Banshee options:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-add-the-banshee-indicator-applet-in-lucid/

Comment: Please when you post an answer don't simply put a link, quote the interesting part (or rewrite it by yourself) and then put the link. You can see more of how to write good answers in [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).