# Change player in sound indicator in Unity

Tags: indicator-sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to control VLC from the Sound Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40107/is-there-a-way-to-control-vlc-from-the-sound-menu)

I was wondering if there is anyway to change the player in sound indicator in Unity.I have checked [previous questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37158/how-do-i-change-the-sound-menus-default-music-player) for my issue,but I wasn't able to make the change.

Comment: 1)http://askubuntu.com/questions/37158/how-do-i-change-the-sound-menus-default-music-player                                              2)http://askubuntu.com/questions/15467/indicator-applet-and-sound-manager-for-oss-sound-system                                      3)http://askubuntu.com/questions/12849/adding-banshee-to-the-sound-indicator                                                    Not all of them are quite related to the question.I was trying to find the answer that's why.

Comment: I am updating the answer now, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Okay I saw the changes.But the weird thing is that I don't have a D-Bus option in my VLC'S Control Interface sub-menu.

Comment: You likely need to follow the instructions I just linked to make sure you're running at least version 2.0.

Comment: The version of my VLC is older!Wait to see if I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you install (and sometimes start) a supported player it should appear there automatically. Mine has right now Rythmbox and Nuvuola.

When I was using Skype it appeared there only after I started it (usually from the dash or the dock).

You can remove an entry from the menu by un-installing the program.

Comment: Well.I installed VLC but it is not there!That's why I am doing the question :) It has only Banshee!

Comment: @el10780 your original question lacked any kind of information as to what player you were using, that's why we've been guessing!